# Running multiple Kobuki bases in the same roscore by changing node names

Tags: ros-kinetic, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I need to run two Qbot2s (Kobuki bases) within the same network using ROS **Kinetic** distro. I have figured out that I need to launch them with different node names.
So I edited my **kobuki/kobuki_node/launch/minimal.launch** file by giving name spaces for the nodes.

```
<launch>
  <arg name="kobuki_publish_tf" default="true"/> 

  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="mobile_base_nodelet_manager" ns="qbot0_nm" args="manager"/>
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="mobile_base" ns="qbot0" args="load kobuki_node/KobukiNodelet mobile_base_nodelet_manager">
    <rosparam file="$(find kobuki_node)/param/base.yaml" command="load"/>
    <param name="publish_tf" value="$(arg kobuki_publish_tf)"/>
    <remap from="mobile_base/odom" to="odom"/>
    <remap from="mobile_base/joint_states" to="joint_states"/>
  </node>
  
  <node pkg="diagnostic_aggregator" type="aggregator_node" name="diagnostic_aggregator" ns="qbot0_da">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find kobuki_node)/param/diagnostics.yaml" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Here I have given namespace parameter for all three nodes available. When I launch the given file, I can see the nodes registered with new names.

```
>> rosnode list 
/qbot0/mobile_base
/qbot0_da/diagnostic_aggregator
/qbot0_nm/mobile_base_nodelet_manager
/rosout
```

But when I look at the rostopic list, I still cannot see the topics relevant to Kobuki base (eg: odom, joint_states etc. ). Here is my **rostopic list**,

```
>> rostopic list
/diagnostics
/diagnostics_agg
/diagnostics_toplevel_state
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

This is the **structure of the rostopic list I should be getting**, (generated by using the original launch file)

```
>> rostopic list
/diagnostics
/diagnostics_agg
/diagnostics_toplevel_state
/joint_states
/mobile_base/commands/controller_info
/mobile_base/commands/digital_output
/mobile_base/commands/external_power
/mobile_base/commands/led1
/mobile_base/commands/led2
/mobile_base/commands/motor_power
/mobile_base/commands/reset_odometry
/mobile_base/commands/sound
/mobile_base/commands/velocity
/mobile_base/controller_info
/mobile_base/debug/raw_control_command
/mobile_base/debug/raw_data_command
/mobile_base/debug/raw_data_stream
/mobile_base/events/bumper
/mobile_base/events/button
/mobile_base/events/cliff
/mobile_base/events/digital_input
/mobile_base/events/power_system
/mobile_base/events/robot_state
/mobile_base/events/wheel_drop
/mobile_base/sensors/core
/mobile_base/sensors/dock_ir
/mobile_base/sensors/imu_data
/mobile_base/sensors/imu_data_raw
/mobile_base/version_info
/mobile_base_nodelet_manager/bond
/odom
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
```

I have an intuition that I need to map the new node names with expected topics, but I do not know how to. Can you help me identify the way I should so this task?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317498/running-multiple-kobuki-bases-in-the-same-roscore-by-changing-node-names./) by [TharushiDeSilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/40232/tharushidesilva/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2019-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll need to run the entire launch file in a namespace. Look into `ROS_NAMESPACE` or (probably preferred): create a new launch file that uses the `ns` attribute on three `include` tags.

There's also quite a few "multiple turtlebot" posts here on ROS Answers. I'd recommend to take a look at those.

---

Edit:

> I included the whole content of the launch file under the required namespace.

just making sure: the [include](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/include) tag supports the `ns` attribute, so you can "push down" entire launch files (and *their* `include`s) into namespaces easily that way. There is no need to do that manually.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TharushiDeSilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/40232/tharushidesilva/) on 2019-03-05**:
@gvdhoorn, Thank you so much for your comment. I looked into some turtlebot answers, and as you mentioned, I included the whole content of the launch file under the required namespace. Then It worked!! Thanks again.